# Roundoff error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @TAX VARCHAR(30)=120.45
DECLARE @TaxRoundOf VARCHAR(30)
SET @TaxRoundOf=ROUND(@TAX,1)
SELECT @TaxRoundOf
```

*This Gives Result **(@TaxRoundOf=120.5)***

```
DECLARE @TAX VARCHAR(30)=146.45
DECLARE @TaxRoundOf VARCHAR(30)
SET @TaxRoundOf=ROUND(@TAX,1)
SELECT @TaxRoundOf
```

*This Gives Result **(@TaxRoundOf=146.4)***

But I need to return `146.50` . why this mismatch between two results?
any one can help plz?

Comment: it's quite evident that the round function is rounding down. You must use the proper function to round up instead.

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR`? If you were to store your numbers using a numeric data type, you would get the results you are expecting.

Comment: Maybe he wants to concatenate that value to some string.

Comment: Convert to decimal or numeric and then apply round function. Should work

Comment: Why would you be rounding values with two decimal places (xxx.45) to a value with two decimal places but rounded to only 1 (xxx.50).  That seems unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also rely on `numeric` rounding instead of converting your string to a `float`, which can lose information.

Cast a string to `numeric` and then round:

```
select round(cast('146.45' as numeric(18,2)), 1)
-- 146.50
```

A decimal constant is already a `decimal` so there's no need to cast it:

```
select round(146.45, 1)
-- 146.50
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `VARCHAR` to store your numbers, SQL Server is having to do implicit conversion to float behind the scenes, which is having knock on effects on your calculations. You can reproduce this using the below query:

```
SELECT  ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, 120.45),1),            -- 120.5
        ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, 146.45),1),            -- 146.4
        ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 120.45),1),   -- 120.50
        ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 146.45),1)    -- 146.50
```

Since [floating point numbers are not exact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895757/1048425), 146.45 cannot be exactly represented as a float, and ends up being stored as a very slightly smaller number, so when this is passed to the round function, it is rounded down, instead of up.

The solution, as demonstrated by the 3rd and 4th columns in the above query, is to use a more precise data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SET @TaxRoundOf=ROUND(10 * CAST(@TAX AS FLOAT)) / 10
```

instead of:

```
SET @TaxRoundOf=ROUND(@TAX,1)
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KDC80860)

PS as @GarethD already mentioned I wouldn't use `@TAX` as `VARCHAR` type.

Comment: Sir In this case its works but if @tax= 146.44 it return 146.50 but right answer is 146.40 is it sir?

Comment: It depends on you which is 'right' answer. I have added in 'DEMO' ROUND and CEIL. Just pick up, what is better for you ;)